# Unable to start ElasticSearch in my machine, StartupException is occuring while executing elasticsearch.bat

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I need to work on elasticSearch, i have downloaded elasticsearch-6.7.2 from authorized website, but while trying to start the ElasticSearch server and while executing `elasticsearch.bat` file, i am getting the below error:

> org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>   Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml
>           at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:107) ~[?:?]
>           at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:98) ~[?:?]
>           at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:413) ~[?:?]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$11(Node.java:472) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
>           at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
>           at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:475) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.2.jar:6.7.2]
>           ... 6 more

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to the ElasticSearch directory:

`C:\elasticsearch-6.7.2\config`

Put the below Entry in your `elasticsearch.yml`:

`xpack.ml.enabled: false`

Answer (score 5):

The error message is pretty straight-forward. X-Pack is not supporting and Machine Learning is not available for windows-x86, so it is not compatible with your operating system.

The reason is that 32-bit architectures are not supported. If you happen to have a 64-bit system OS, then something else makes it think that you are using a 32-bit environment. Check your JVM and see whether it is 32-bit or not. If it's 32 bit, then that's the problem.

It can also be caused by an unsupported CPU as per the following warning from elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ml-settings.html). In this case, you can disable the option by adding `xpack.ml.enabled: false` to [`elasticsearch.yml`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html).
[image]

Comment: Thankful for the insights , but i just resolved the issue  by disabling ML

Comment: @AkashRoy that's a solution if and only if you do not want to use Machine Learning. If you do not want to restrict yourself, you can make sure that it's a 64-bit env.

Comment: What is the likely course if `java --version` has the following output? ```openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)```

Answer (score 0):

**Logs which I have got:**

```
Failure running machine learning native code. This could be due to running on an unsupported OS or distribution, missing OS libraries, or a problem with the temp directory. To bypass this problem by running Elasticsearch without machine learning functionality set [xpack.ml.enabled: false].]
```

Tested on the given combination:

- macOS: Catalina, Version: 10.15.4
- Java Version: 11.0.4
- ElasticVersion: 7.6.2

The possible workaround is by setting `x-pack-ml.enabled: false`, in the `elasticsearch.yml` file.

For more detail click [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ml-settings.html)